# kendo ui grid background change event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a Kendo UI Grid that is changing the bg color of each row due to a condition in the databound event like this:

```
function onDataBound(e) {

    var grid = $("#Software").data("kendoGrid");
    var gridData = grid.dataSource.view();

    for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
        var currentUid = gridData[i].uid;
        if (gridData[i].CategoryID == 1) {
            var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
            $(currenRow).addClass("green");
        }
        else if (gridData[i].CategoryID == 2 ){
            var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
            $(currenRow).addClass("red");
        }
        else {
            var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
            $(currenRow).addClass("yellow");
        }
    }
}
```

I have a custom column where 3 buttons are given to categorize. What I want to do now, is to change the background color of a row, when one of these buttons is clicked.

The background color changes, when the grid is reloaded, but this takes far too long 'cause the grid is filled with a lot of data.

I only want to add e.g. the css class "green" to the affected row.

```
function SetGreen(sid, cid) {

    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    cid =1;
    var url = '@Url.Action("SetMethod","SetController")';

    $.post(url, { SID: sid, CID: cid });

    grid.saveChanges();

    //right here I want to set the bg color for the affected row
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [rowTemplate](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-rowTemplate) of the grid to set the CSS class of the table row (tr) element rendered for every data item. Something like this:

```
var categoryClassNames = {
  1: "red",
  2: "green"
};

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: [
    { Category: 1 },
    { Category: 2 },
    { Category: 1 }
  ],
  rowTemplate: "<tr data-uid='#=uid#' class='#= categoryClassNames[Category]#'>" + 
                 "<td>#= Category #</td>" + 
               "</tr>"
});
```

To update a specific table row you can use the following code:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var itemToUpdate = grid.dataSource.at(1); // we will update the second item

itemToUpdate.Category = 1;

$("#grid tr[data-uid='" + itemToUpdate.uid + "']").removeClass("green").addClass("red");
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/iNExotO/2/edit

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the row color is already set in the databound event when the grid loads.
what I need to know, is how I can change the background color if one of the 3 buttons is clicked.

Comment: You need to update the corresponding field and refresh the grid.

Comment: hey atanas - and that is exactly the point. I dont want to refresh the grid, 'cause it contains about 10k entries - this would take far too long. the only thing I want to do is, to add the css class to the corresponding table row immideately, to mark the row as categorized.

Comment: You can then locate the corresponding row based on it's data-uid attribute. That attribute is set to the uid of the data item to which the row is bound to. Will update my response ...